# Run javascript unit test with facebook jest to connect to mongodb, but not work

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, jestjs

I have a snippet of unit test which use a "connect" function to connect to mongodb with package "mongodb"， the "connect" function never work in unit test environment, but it works in production mode. The function code is below:

```js
import mongo from 'mongodb'
import Promise from 'bluebird'

connect() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const url = this.getConnectionURL()

    const client = mongo.MongoClient

    client.connect(url)
      .then((db) => {
        // never goes here in unit test environment.
        this._db = db
        resolve(db)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  })
}
```

I run the unit test with facebook jest. Thanks!

Comment: And what is the connection error ?

Comment: There is no any error message. When it runs in unit test, it seems jest just ignore the "client.connect".

Comment: So inside your `catch` you can log an error ? Is Jest expecting a callback ? What is the difference with Production and Test environments ? Actually, inside your `then`, check for error ?

Comment: There is no any error catched in catch block. The production environment is running my project with "yarn start", the test environment is runing unit test with "npm run test -- example.test.ts"

Comment: If there is no error in catch then nothing is thrown in `connect`, you are better to listen for disconnect events and see what is happening..

Comment: when I print log in the comment line, it never shows. So the connection is not built yet.

Comment: I suspect you are returning a promise object, before your async call of `connect` is complete.  depending on what `jest` is expecting you should `await` the connect to DB call. Ensuring you have the connection before resolving.

Comment: Can you show your test `jest` caller code also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168197/discussion-between-pogrindis-and-peng-wu).

Comment: The `jest` caller inside is just one function call, and finally it would run into the `connect()`